# How to hide(display:none) parent div when child(img) fails to load?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My code looks like this:

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
     <img src="#">
  </a>
</div>
```

When `img` fails loading or missing, the parent `div` must be hidden (`display:none`), so that it will not leave an empty space but removes itself from existence.  How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do here is trigger the `onload` and/or `onerror` events by creating an in memory image element and setting its `src` attribute to the original `src` attribute of the original image.

Refer code:

```
$("<img/>")
    .on('load', function() { console.log("image loaded correctly"); })
    .on('error', function() { $(this).parent().parent().hide(); })
    .attr("src", $(originalImage).attr("src"));
```

Comment: [Result](http://imgur.com/a/LCpc7) Its hiding the error thumbnail, but no the `div`.

Comment: Try `$(this).parent().parent().hide();` then. Immediate parent was the anchor tag, so might not have worked. Parent's parent is the `div` so it should remove it. Also updated my answer.